# Find amount of steps.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate the amount of steps the person needs to take to have a probability of 50% to be aleast 10m away from his starting point (in both directions). He has a probability of 50% of moving in either direction.

Could someone tell if I'm thinking the right way or set me in the good direction. That would be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, it's the first time I asked a question. Is this better now?

Comment: Yes, it is better now.

Comment: Does he move 1 meter with each step?

Comment: @DanielP yes he does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_t = \text{How far away the drunkard is from the origin after } t \text{ steps}$; $X_t$ is a random variable.

We're interested in $t$, as
$$\Bbb{P}(|X_t| \ge 3 ) = 0.95$$
Which is the probability of the drunkard being **at least** $3$ meters away from the origin, after $t$ steps. (Which we know is $95\%$.)

So we need to find the distribution of $X_t$ for $t \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Since $X_t$ is gotten through $t$ steps that are exactly alike, it makes sense to introduce another notation:

$$X_t = M_1 + M_2 + M_3, + \dots + M_t$$

where $\forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,t\} \ \ M_i $ are random (left or right) movements, a.k.a. random variables with distribution

$$M_i = \begin{cases}+1 \text{ with probablity } \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex] -1 \text{ with probablity } \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

So $M_i \sim 2\ \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1$

Note: Regular $\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is $\begin{cases}1 \text{ with probablity } \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \text{ with probablity } \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$, so multiplying it with $2$ and subtracting $1$ transforms it into the type of variable we're looking for.

We can find a pattern and prove it by induction:

$$\begin{align}M_1 + M_2 &= \begin{cases}2 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{4} \\[2ex] 0 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4} \\[2ex] -2 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{4}\end{cases} \\[2ex]
M_1 + M_2 + M_3 &= \begin{cases}3 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{8} \\[2ex] 1 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{8} \\[2ex] -1 \text{ with probability } \frac{3}{8} \\[2ex] -3 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{8}\end{cases} \\[2ex]
M_1 + M_2 + M_3 + M_4 &= \begin{cases}4 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{16} \\[2ex] 2 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{8} = \frac{4}{16} \\[2ex] 0 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{8} = \frac{6}{16} \\[2ex]  -2 \text{ with probability } \frac{4}{16} \\[2ex] -4 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{16} \end{cases} \\[2ex]
&\quad \vdots \\[2ex]
\sum_{i=1}^t M_i &=  t-2j \text{ with probability } \frac{\binom{t}{j}}{2^t} \quad \forall j \in \{0,1,\dots,t\}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$
Or
$$\Bbb{P}(X_t = t-2j) = \Bbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^t M_i = t-2j\right) = \frac{\binom{t}{j}}{2^t}, \quad \forall j \in \{0,1,\dots,t\}$$
Which isn't very suprising, since the sum of $\text{Bernoulli}$ variables has $\text{Binomial}$ distribution. We just had to slightly modify the $\text{Binomial}$ distribution, since we had $2 \text{Bernoulli} -1 $ instead of $\text{Bernoulli}$.

The proof is very simple, it works for $t=1$:

$$M_1 = \begin{cases}1 \text{ with probablity } \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{2^1} = \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex] 1-2 = -1 \text{ with probablity } \frac{\binom{1}{0}}{2^1} = \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

Let's assume it works up until $t-1$ and prove for $t$:

$$\begin{align}&\Bbb{P}(M_1 + \dots + M_t = t-2j) = \\ = &\frac{1}{2}\Bbb{P}(M_1+\dots+M_{t-1} = (t-1)-2(j-1)) + \frac{1}{2}\Bbb{P}(M_1+\dots+M_{t-1} = (t-1)-2j) = \\ = &\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\binom{t-1}{j-1}+\binom{t-1}{j}}{2^{t-1}}\right) \stackrel{\text{Pascal-triangle rule}}{=} \frac{\binom{t}{j}}{2^t}\end{align}$$

So

$$\begin{align}\Bbb{P}(|X_t| \ge 3) &= 0.95 \\
\sum_{i=3}^\infty \Bbb{P}(X_t=i) + \sum_{i=3}^\infty \Bbb{P}(X_t=-i) &= 0.95 \\
\Bbb{P}(X_t=2) + \Bbb{P}(X_t=1) + \Bbb{P}(X_t=0) + \Bbb{P}(X_t=-1)+ \Bbb{P}(X_t=-2) &= 0.05 \\[1ex]
2\Bbb{P}(X_t=2) + 2\Bbb{P}(X_t=1) + \Bbb{P}(X_t=0) &= 0.05 \\
\end{align}$$

Since $j$ has to be in $j \in \{0,1,\dots,t\}$, and $t$ has to be odd (since as we saw earlier, you can only get to an odd value in odd number of steps), this eliminates a couple options:

$$0 = t-2j \rightarrow j = \frac{t}{2} \rightarrow j \notin \{0,1,\dots,t\}$$
$$1 = t-2j \rightarrow j = \frac{t-1}{2} \rightarrow j \in \{0,1,\dots,t\}$$
$$2 = t-2j \rightarrow j = \frac{t-2}{2} \rightarrow j \notin \{0,1,\dots,t\}$$

This simplifies the above equation to

$$\begin{align}
2\Bbb{P}(X_t=1) &= 0.05 \\
\frac{\binom{t}{\frac{t-1}{2}}}{2^t} &= 0.025 \\
\end{align}$$
We can solve this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%28t%2C%28t-1%29%2F2%29%3D2%5Et*0.025), but we unfortunately get no $t > 0$ solution, which means **the probability of the drunkard travelling at least $3$ meters can never go above $95\%$**.

This is easy to see, since for the equivalent equation

$$\begin{align}
\binom{t}{\frac{t-1}{2}} &= 2^t \cdot 0.025 \\
\end{align}$$

The left side is approximately

$$\begin{align}
\binom{t}{\frac{t-1}{2}} &\approx \binom{t}{\frac{t}{2}} = \frac{t!}{\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)!^2}\\
\end{align}$$

Which has a lower bound for $t \ge 0$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{t!}{\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)!^2} \ge 1
\end{align}$$

And then grows more rapidly than $2^t \cdot 0.025$.

However, with different inputs, like $5$ meters instead of $3$, or a different probability than $0.95$, we can likely find a solution, since the above approximation won't be accurate - meaning the left and right sides can actually meet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a mistake in my question, it's actually 4m. I'm going to try this myself.

Comment: I just tested it with $P(X >= 4)$ and I also don't find a valid $t$. I find this weird because I think I should be able to find an answer. As my final equation I had: $$ \binom{t}{\frac{t-1}{2}} + \binom{t}{\frac{t-3}{2}} &= 2^t \cdot 0.025 $$. Sorry but I don't know how to make the formula show. @Daniel P

Comment: Use dollar signs on the 2 sides of your equation to turn it into a formula. @Yeonsan

Comment: This is my formula: $\binom{t} {\frac{t - 1}{2}} + \binom{t} {\frac{t - 3}{2}} = 2^t . 0.025$

Comment: I think this time it should be $\binom{t} {\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \binom{t} {\frac{t - 2}{2}} = 2^t . 0.05$, since this time $t$ is even. Note that we observed that $M_1 + \dots + M_t$ can only be odd if $t$ is odd, and can only be even if $t$ is even.

Comment: If it's even shouldn't it also include $2 \binom{t}{\frac{t - 4}{2}}$

Comment: Depending on what we're trying to find. If the question is $\Bbb{P}(|X_t| > 4)$, then the compliment should include that term, but if the question is $\Bbb{P}(|X_t| \ge 4)$, then it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, but again I can't seem to get a valid answer. Is this normal?

Comment: It is with 4 not included btw

Comment: WolframAlpha shows generalized factorials, and that's why we're getting negative terms, but nonetheless it should give a positive solution if there is one. However it's entirely possible that there isn't one - it's likely that the drunkard stays close to the origin, and we can never be $95\%$ sure that he is outside of the $[-3,3]$ interval. Try multiplying with a bigger number, for example for $\binom{t}{t/2}+2\binom{t}{(t-2)/2}=2^t\cdot 0.9$, we can get a feasable solution of $t \approx 3.55$

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first posed question which was later edited

---

The target will be reached in an odd number of steps.

Let $S_{m}$ denote the number of steps that separate the drunkard
from the target after taking $1+2m$ steps.

Then $S_{0}=2$ and $S_{1}\in\left\{ 0,2\right\} $ so a walk that
ends with $S_{m}=0$ will have shape: $$\left(S_{0},S_{1},\dots,S_{m-1},S_{m}\right)=\left(2,2,\dots,2,0\right)$$

After taking exactly one step we are in status $S_{0}=2$ and there
are $3$ possible outcomes for the next two steps:

- It is a loop of $2$ steps that hits the original starting point.
  This has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to occur.
- It is a loop of $2$ steps that does not hit the original starting
  position. This has probability $\frac{1}{4}$ to occur.
- It is an arrival at the target. This has probability $\frac{1}{4}$
  to occur.

So - taking the first two bullets together - when the first
step is taken and the next $2$ steps are taken then there is probability $\frac{3}{4}$ on making a loop and probability $\frac{1}{4}$ on reaching the target.

That means that the probability that the target is reached in exactly
$1+2m$ steps equals: $$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m-1}$$ for $m=1,2,\dots$.

Then the probability of reaching the target in at most $1+2m$ steps
is: $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1}=1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m}$$

To be found is the smallest $m$ that satisfies $1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m}\geq0.95$ which is $m_0:=11$

So the final answer is: $$n_0=1+2m_0=23$$

---

**edit** (answer to edited question)

For $n=0,1,2,\dots$ let $X_{n}$ denote the distance of the drunkard
from his starting point.

Then to be found are expressions for $P\left(X_{n}=i\right)$ for
$i=0,1,2,3$.

After finding them we can go for finding the smallest $n$ that satisfies:

$$1-P\left(X_{n}=0\right)-P\left(X_{n}=1\right)-P\left(X_{n}=2\right)-P\left(X_{n}=3\right)\geq0.95$$
or equivalently: $$P\left(X_{n}=0\right)+P\left(X_{n}=1\right)+P\left(X_{n}=2\right)+P\left(X_{n}=3\right)\leq0.05$$

Under the convention that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\left\{ 0,1,2,\dots,n\right\} $ we find for nonnegative integer $n$:

- $P\left(X_{n}=0\right)=2^{-n}\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n}$
- $P\left(X_{n}=1\right)=2^{-n}\left[\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{1}{2}}+\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}}\right]$
- $P\left(X_{n}=2\right)=2^{-n}\left[\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n-1}+\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n+1}\right]$
- $P\left(X_{n}=3\right)=2^{-n}\left[\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{3}{2}}+\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{3}{2}}\right]$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Do you mean "destination" by "destiny"? :)

Comment: @DanielP Lol, Yes I guess so. Destiny goes too far. The man must at least get a second chance. I will repair, thank you.

Comment: I found an error in my answer and repaired.

Comment: @drhab I made the mistake of saying that he needs to be 3m away from his origin, it should've been 4m. Does this mean that $S_m$ is now the difference in distance from the target with $2m$ steps?

Comment: @drhab Note: It should be atleast 4m. So he can be farther away from his starting point.

Comment: I would go for another setup then. See the edit of my answer.